# PHP Insert SQL date

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-insert

I have this code:

```
$date = '1991-08-13';

$sql =  "INSERT into TABLEA
        (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direccion, codigoPostal,fechaNacimiento, notas) 
        VALUES 
        ('agds', 'asdgff', 'gerth', 'dfghdfghd efdgvwr', 86486, $date, 'ShhhHH');";
```

My problem is the next one:

When I insert that $date's value is: `1991-13-08` but in the DB appears: `0000-00-00` 
I've seen other posts with solutions like: `STR_TO_DATE()` and it dosen't work for me, it inserts NULL. Any other solution?

EDIT: missing: '' in $date (it should have been: '$date') Thanks for the correction! (:

Comment: That date is in the wrong format. Mysql dates are `yyyy-mm-dd`. If it is a date column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL str\_to\_date produces NULL despite valid formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356813/mysql-str-to-date-produces-null-despite-valid-formatting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please enclose the $date with single quotes like

```
$sql = "INSERT into TABLEA (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direccion, codigoPostal,fechaNacimiento, notas) VALUES ('agds', 'asdgff', 'gerth', 'dfghdfghd efdgvwr', 86486, '$date', 'ShhhHH');";
```

Comment: you will also need to convert the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format

Comment: The date wasnt in that format, i just typed it wrong. It was exactly what @Arun Krish said.

Comment: @Roucher if Arun's answer is correct than I think you selected the wrong answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Both are correct, because both mark the error: '$date' the main reason that I choosed the other one was the time. Imran posted it before, But it's true Arun explained it better

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try by this way:

```
$date = '1991-08-13'; //yyyy-mm-dd

$sql =  "INSERT into TABLEA
        (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, direccion, codigoPostal,fechaNacimiento, notas) 
        VALUES 
        ('agds', 'asdgff', 'gerth', 'dfghdfghd efdgvwr', 86486, '$date', 'ShhhHH');";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Str_to_date`

```
Str_to_date('1991-13-08','%Y-%d-%m')
```

or try this :-

```
$sql = "INSERT into TABLEA (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, 
direccion, codigoPostal,fechaNacimiento, notas) 
VALUES ('agds', 'asdgff', 'gerth', 'dfghdfghd efdgvwr',
86486, Str_to_date("1991-13-08","%Y-%d-%m"), 'ShhhHH');";
```

Comment: "I've seen other posts with solutions like: STR_TO_DATE() and it dosen't work for me, it inserts NULL"

Comment: $sql = "INSERT into TABLEA (nombre, apellido1, apellido2, 
direccion, codigoPostal,fechaNacimiento, notas) 
VALUES ('agds', 'asdgff', 'gerth', 'dfghdfghd efdgvwr',
86486, Str_to_date("1991-13-08","%Y-%d-%m"), 'ShhhHH');";

Comment: try this query @Roucher

Comment: Returns NULL, I can't comprehend why you focus on saying "str_to_date" if i had already said twice that wasnt that and said the correction, thanks for the attempts anyways

Comment: I think i might not be understanding you, but data format (not mine) is specified here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html